# Script to detect which devices have Bitlocker enabled and then export it

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-remoting

I have been trying to get this Powershell script in the code block below working in order to check all the pcs on the domain and see if they have bitlocker/ the drives it is encrypted on.
Right now it is running and giving this error on all computers except one:

Test-Connection : Invalid parameter
At line:6 char:13

- ```
      If (Test-Connection $Computer -Count 1){
  ```
- ```
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Test-Connection], ManagementException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestConnectionException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestConnection
    Command

- The one computer that does output fine to the .txt with the bitlocker info, is then deleted from the file after the script fully runs.

Any idea as to why these issues may be happening? Would PSremote need to be allowed on a gpo level?

```
$TextFilePath = "C:\Users\test.txt"
If (Test-Path $TextFilePath){
    $ComputersArray = Get-Content $TextFilePath
    $ComputerStatusCol = @()
ForEach ($Computer in $ComputersArray) {
        If (Test-Connection $Computer -Count 1){
            $ComputerStatus = manage-bde -status -cn "$Computer" |
    Out-File -filepath "c:\users\gnishku\desktop\Bitlocker-Status.txt" -append -force
            $ComputerStatusCol += $ComputerStatus
        } Else {
            Write-Host("$Computer appears to be offline.")
        }
    }
    $ComputerStatusCol | Out-File -filepath "c:\users\test2.txt"
} Else {
    Write-Error "The text file was not found, check the path."
}
```

I have tried editing the script to see if that would help but keep getting the same appears to be offline error, even though the computers are online and on the domain

Comment: Sumerius, welcome to SO! I think you want to add the -Append parameter to your Out-File statements so you don't overwrite previous outputs.